# 'Impact' field on new user profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page

Since the user profile page has been redesigned, and very nice it is too, there is now an item of data named 'Impact'. On my own profile, this has a value of "~2k people reached".

What does "Impact" actually mean, and how is it measured?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here

Comment: Gosh. Based on 10 for an upvote, I'd have estimated myself at reaching maybe 40 people. I'm now trying to visualise what ~2,000 people would look like.